# Java: Jasper report chart parameter issue

Tags: java, parameters, jasper-reports

I have a stacked bar chart which requires a parameter when I add in the value with results it works. But when I add in a value in the parameter with no results the entire chart disappears. Is there way I can just show the chart with no results if the value, results is empty?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is in **When No data** column, select **All Sections,No details** .
To do so, select your report in Report Inspector. Right Click and go to Properties. In **More** section, navigate to **When No Data** and select **All Sections,No details** .This will display the chart without values when there is no data.